# Percentage Change versus Percentage Difference

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, percentages

I have two processors running the same benchmark. Processor A completes the benchmark in `42.5` seconds, and Processor B completes it in `32.9` seconds. **The goal is to determine how much faster Processor B is than Processor A.**

With benchmark results indicating "higher is better", that's simple: you divide the larger number by the smaller number. With benchmark results indicating "lower is better", however, do I do the same thing? Am I to find the percentage change between the two numbers, or their percentage difference? Up until now, I've been using computation #1:

1. $$(42.5 / 32.9)  - 1 = 29.179\%$$
2. $$1 - (32.9 / 42.5) = 22.588\%$$

Could someone help explain the difference between these two calculations, and which one I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful to think of it this way: A processor's speed is inversely proportional to the time it takes to complete the task. Therefore, for processor A we can give a "non-dimensional speed" of $\frac{1}{42.5}$. For processor B, this value is $\frac{1}{32.9}$. It's easy to see that B is faster in this case, because the speed is greater.

Now you want to compare their speeds, or in particular answer the question "How many per cent is processor B faster than A?". So you can just calculate the ratio of their speeds like this:
$$
\frac{\left( \frac{1}{32.9}\right)}{\left( \frac{1}{42.5}\right)} = \frac{42.5}{32.9}\approx 1.2917
$$
Therefore, our answer is: Processor B is faster than processor A by $29.2~\%$.

Should you calculate it the other way around, you'd be asking the question "How much slower is processor A compared to processor B?".

Comment: Hi Matti. Thank you so much. You answered everything that I wanted to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Processor A completes the benchmark in `42.5` seconds, and Processor B completes it in `32.9` seconds. **The goal is to determine how much faster Processor B is against Processor A.**

Let $p$ denote te number of floating-point operations executed by the benchmark; then Processors A and B have speeds $\dfrac p{42.5}$ FLOPS and $\dfrac p{32.9}$ FLOPS, respectively.

So, B is $$\dfrac{\frac p{32.9}-\frac p{42.5}}{\left|\frac p{42.5}\right|}= 29.179\%$$ faster than A, as required.

---

> 1. $$(42.5 / \boldsymbol{32.9})  - 1 = 29.179\%$$

This means that A takes $29\%$ more time **than B** to complete the benchmark. (Here, B is the comparison baseline or reference point.)

> 2. $$1 - (32.9 / \boldsymbol{42.5}) = 22.588\%$$

This means that B takes $23\%$ less time **than A** to complete the benchmark. (Here, A is the comparison baseline or reference point.)

> the percentage change between the two numbers, or their percentage difference?

"Percentage change" is not really applicable here. On the other hand, the *percentage difference between speeds A and B* is [commonly](https://www.google.com/search?q=percentage+difference) [computed as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference#Indicators_of_relative_change) $$\dfrac{\frac p{32.9}-\frac p{42.5}}{\frac12\left|\frac p{42.5}+\frac p{32.9}\right|}= 25.464\%.$$

Comment: Your unit of "speed" in this answer appears to be the time taken to do a fixed number of calculations. Less time is faster, more is slower. Most people measure "speed" of a processor in number of calculations done in a fixed length of time. More calculation is faster, less is slower. Not surprisingly, you get different results for percentage change in "speed". (Measuring speed by elapsed time can be very useful, so this is merely an observation, not necessarily a criticism.)

Comment: I'm trying to elaborate both answers. $5$ seconds elapsed time is $25\%$ more than $4$ seconds, but $5$ MFLOPS is $25\%$ more than $4$ MFLOPS. The use of percentages is sometimes a bit arbitrary and dependent on usage more than logic.

Comment: Another good example of how comparisons can be ambiguous when we embed the numbers in English-language statements.

Comment: @DavidK Oh, I hadn't noticed that the other answer had come to a different conclusion from mine. Thanks for that valuable point! **I've just changed my answer.**